# Index Match Match search multiple columns for column value. e.g. if not in this column then next

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

I am looking for a solution for this screenshot. Explanation is: I want a value in a cell returnd using [index match match] or some other formula to look into column A, if that's not found then next or even next if not found there.

After finding value in any column it should search row with second part of [match] in the formula.

Please help me formulate it.

The current formula: **=INDEX(B3:I17, MATCH(TODAY()+1,B3:B17,0), MATCH("G-devotee",B3:I3,0))**

[image]

Comment: If the dates in your table each only occur once (which looks to be the case), you can use this sort of approach to find the row or column with matching date https://exceljet.net/formula/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array . Once you've found the right row, you can use Index to get the matching value from the g-devotee column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE() as the second criterion in the INDEX instead of MATCH:

```
=INDEX(F:I, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B4:E17)/(TODAY()+1=B4:E17),1), MATCH("G-devotee",F3:I3,0))
```

Comment: I's looking ths for a long and you solved it for me with exact formula. Thank you so much, Scott.

Comment: But I want to know more about Agrregate formula.Could you please give me some online material or suggest a good place.